# Reading a XML where a data type has been changed

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a C# program that's creating a deeply nested List. I'm Serializing (XML) the List to save all the user inputs in the program and I'm able to Deserialize (XML) the file in order to restore the user inputs in the List.

After Serializing the List I recently changed a couple of variables in my program from Boolean to a user defined Type because true/false was not defining their property correctly.

Now when I try to Deserialize the file I get an exception stating that I don't have a valid value for the variable. This makes total makes sense.

The question is whether there is something I can do in my code so that the Deserialization would use the current default value if the types don't match. Presently I can't read the file at all.

Below is my code for deserializing the file.

```
xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType(strCampusType), GlobalClass.objRunApplication.m_ListOfSerializableTypes.ToArray());
stream = File.OpenRead(strFileName);
try
{
  objCampusCopy = (CAMPUS)xmlserializer.Deserialize(stream);      
  if (objCampusCopy != null)
  {...}
}
catch {}
```

Comment: Can you post the XML file and class as well? Also do you want to desrialzie this peroperty or want to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try attributing the field in question as follows:

```
[OptionalField]
```

More info here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.110).aspx